# jQuery is not working with the autofill for my textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery stopped working, I changed the library im using and migrated some code from another project. The textboxes are auto populating data from mySQL and then you can select them from the list. I see the populated list when you type something in the textbox but nothing get filled into the textbox if you click on an item from the list.

Here is my code, any help for this beginner will be great ! :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Boekingsfilter</title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OrganicTabs/css/style.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JqueryUI/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="OrganicTabs/js/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function() {    
    $("#example-one").organicTabs();               
});

function lookup(inputString) {
    if (inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_naam_klant.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0){    
                $('#suggestions').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function lookup2(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions2').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_boekingsnummer.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0) {    
                $('#suggestions2').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList2').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function lookup3(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions3').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_bedrag_van_boete.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0){    
                $('#suggestions3').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList3').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function lookup4(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions4').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_distributiekanaal.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0){    
                $('#suggestions4').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList4').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function lookup5(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions5').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_huiscode.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0){    
                $('#suggestions5').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList5').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function lookup6(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions6').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_huursom.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0){    
                $('#suggestions6').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList6').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function lookup7(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions7').hide();
    }    
    else {    
        $.post("sql_opmerking.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
        function(data) {   
            if(data.length >0){    
                $('#suggestions7').show();    
                $('#autoSuggestionsList7').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}    

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#naam_klant').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);        
}

function fill2(thisValue) {
    $('#boekingsnummer').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions2').hide();", 200);        
}    

function fill3(thisValue) {
    $('#bedrag_van_boete').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions3').hide();", 200);        
}

function fill4(thisValue) {
    $('#distributiekanaal').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions4').hide();", 200);        
}    

function fill5(thisValue) {
    $('#huiscode').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions5').hide();", 200);        
}

function fill6(thisValue) {
    $('#huursom').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions6').hide();", 200);        
}    

function fill7(thisValue) {
    $('#opmerking').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions7').hide();", 200);        
}  

</script>
```

Beginscherm

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Boekings filter</h1>        

    <div id="example-one">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="a"><a href="#medewerker" class="current">Medewerker</a></li>
            <li class="b"><a href="#datum_overboeking" class="current">Datum overboeking</a></li>
            <li class="c"><a href="#juliete_geinformeerd" class="current">Juliette geinformeerd</a></li>
            <li class="d"><a href="#boekingsnummer" class="current">Boekingsnummer</a></li>
            <li class="e"><a href="#land" class="current">Land</a></li>
            <li class="f"><a href="#huiscode" class="current">Huiscode</a></li>
            <li class="g"><a href="#aanbieder" class="current">Aanbieder</a></li><br><br><br>
            <li class="h"><a href="#contractvorm" class="current">Contractvorm</a></li>
            <li class="i"><a href="#huursom" class="current">Huursom</a></li>
            <li class="j"><a href="#periode_van" class="current">Periode van</a></li>
            <li class="k"><a href="#periode_tot" class="current">Periode tot</a></li>
            <li class="l"><a href="#distributiekanaal" class="current">Distributiekanaal</a></li>
            <li class="m"><a href="#naam_klant" class="current">Naam klant</a></li>
            <li class="n"><a href="#reden" class="current">Reden</a></li><br><br><br>
            <li class="o"><a href="#nieuwe_boeking" class="current">Nieuwe boeking</a></li>
            <li class="p"><a href="#reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" class="current">Reden geen nieuwe boeking</a></li>
            <li class="q"><a href="#boete_aanbieden" class="current">Boete aanbieden</a></li>
            <li class="r"><a href="#administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" class="current">Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete</a></li>
            <li class="s"><a href="#bedrag_van_boete" class="current">Bedrag van boete</a></li>
            <li class="t"><a href="#coulance_happyhome" class="current">Coulance Happyhome</a></li>
            <li class="u"><a href="#opmerking" class="current">Opmerking</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="list-wrap">
        <ul id="medewerker" class="hide">               
            <li><label for="medewerker"><h4>Medewerker</h4></label><br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker">Charlene<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker1">Ellen<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker2">Esmeralda<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker3">Lieke<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker4">Mandy<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker5">Manon<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker6">Samantha<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker7">Sonja<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker8">Susan<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker9">Susanne<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker10">Simone<br></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="datum_overboeking" class="hide">             
            <li><label for="datum_overboeking"><h4>Datum overboeking</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="datum_overboeking" name="datum_overboeking"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="juliete_geinformeerd" class="hide">               
            <li><label for="juliete_geinformeerd"><h4>Juliette geinformeerd</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="juliette_geinformeerd" name="juliette_geinformeerd1">ja<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="juliette_geinformeerd" name="juliette_geinformeerd2">nee</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="boekingsnummer" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Boekingsnummer</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="boekingsnummer" onkeyup="lookup2(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList2"></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="land" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="land"><h4>Land</h4></label>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land1">Nederland<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land2">België<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land3">Duitsland<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land4">Frankrijk<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land5">Hongarije<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land6">Italië<br></li>          
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land7">Kroatië<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land8">Luxemburg<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land9">Oostenrijk<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land10">Slovenië<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land11">Spanje<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land12">Tsjechië<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land13">Zwitserland<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="huiscode" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>huiscode</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="huiscode" size="20" id="huiscode" onkeyup="lookup5(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions5" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList5"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="aanbieder" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="aanbieder"><h4>Aanbieder</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder1">Agent<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder2">Camping<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder3">Park<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder4">Particulier<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="contractvorm" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="contractvorm"><h4>Contractvorm</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="contractvorm" name="contractvorm1">Aanvraag<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="contractvorm" name="contractvorm2">Exclusiviteit<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="contractvorm" name="contractvorm3">Prioriteit<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="huursom" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>huursom</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="huursom" size="20" id="huursom" onkeyup="lookup6(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions6" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList6"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="periode_van" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="periode_van"><h4>Periode van</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="periode_van" name="periode_van"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="periode_tot" class="hide">
            <li><label for="periode_tot"><h4>Periode tot</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="periode_tot" name="periode_tot"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="distributiekanaal" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Distributiekanaal</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="distributiekanaal" onkeyup="lookup4(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions4" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList4"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="naam_klant" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Naam klant</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="reden" class="hide">
            <li><label for="reden"><h4>Reden</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden1">Agent mistake did not informed HappyHome about EV<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden2">Agent mistake did not block in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden3">Calamities ( can not rent) Sale<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden4">Contract is not extended<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden5">Create Double allotment in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden6">Exit<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden7">HappyHome mistake blokking not all<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden8">HappyHome mistake blokking to late in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden9">Other<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden10">Park/Camping mistake did not block in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden11">Park/Camping mistake did not informed HappyHome about EV<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden12">Privat owner mistake did not block in LandLord<br></li>                 
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden13">Privat owner mistake did not informed HappyHome about EV<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden14">Stamgasten (regular guests)<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden15">Itea<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden16">Price is not correct misstake owner<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden17">Inkoper niet juiste contractform aangehouden<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden18">To many people<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="nieuwe_boeking" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="nieuwe_boeking"><h4>Nieuwe boeking</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="nieuwe_boeking" name="nieuwe_boeking1">No<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="nieuwe_boeking" name="nieuwe_boeking2">Yes<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="nieuwe_boeking" name="nieuwe_boeking3">Not Yet<br></li>
        </ul>             

        <ul id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking"><h4>Reden geen nieuwe boeking</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking1">Guest did booked somewhere else<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking2">No good alternative in that area<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking3">Guest did not response<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking4">Otherwhise ….. Fillin true -> Esmeralda<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="boete_aanbieden" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="boete_aanbieden"><h4>Boete aanbieden</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="boete_aanbieden" name="boete_aanbieden1">Yes<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="boete_aanbieden" name="boete_aanbieden2">No<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete"><h4>Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" name="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete1">Yes<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" name="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete2">No<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" name="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete3">Not yet<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="bedrag_van_boete" class="hide">                
            <li><label>Bedrag van boete</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="bedrag_van_boete" size="20" id="bedrag_van_boete" onkeyup="lookup3(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList3"></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="coulance_happyhome" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="coulance_happyhome"><h4>Coulance Happyhome</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome1">Coulance Agent<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome2">Coulance Camping<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome3">Coulance Park<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome4">Coulance Privatowner<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome5">Coulance HappyHome<br></li>   
        </ul>

        <ul id="opmerking" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Opmerking</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="opmerking" size="20" id="opmerking" onkeyup="lookup7(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions7" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList7"></li>
        </ul>      
        </div>
    </div>

<table id="employees">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th>Medewerker</th>
            <th>Datum overboeking</th>
            <th>Juliette geinformeerd</th>
            <th>Boekingsnummer</th>
            <th>Land</th>
            <th>Huiscode</th>
            <th>Aanbieder</th>
            <th>Contractvorm</th>
            <th>Huursom</th>
            <th>Periode van</th>
            <th>Periode tot</th>
            <th>Distributiekanaal</th>
            <th>Naam klant</th>
            <th>Reden</th>
            <th>Nieuwe boeking</th>
            <th>Reden geen nieuwe boeking</th>
            <th>Boete aanbieden</th>
            <th>Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete</th>
            <th>Bedrag van boete</th>
            <th>Coulance Happyhome</th>
            <th>Opmerking</th>
            <th>Id</th>                
        </thead>
    </tr>
</table>                    
</div>
```

Comment: It would probably help to see the HTML